# Deploying Create-React-App with Rails API on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I'm having an issue getting my react /rails app to work on heroku. I've managed to get it deployed and the rails server starts but I'm not seeing my react app. I feel like I'm close but can't figure out what's missing.

So my process is currently to run `npm run build` locally from the client directory which builds a 'build' directory in client. I then commit the results of the build and push to Heroku with `git push heroku master`.

I then navigate to the heroku app in a browser where I'm only getting a blank white page which is an index file the I manually copied from the build dir to public. I'm not sure if the index file is correct but I just wanted to make sure i could hit something.

Ultimately, I would like to just push the repo and it automatically run the build. I've seen this mentioned various places but I always get a react-script does not exist error when I run `npm run build` on the server.

My configuration is as follows:

basic structure of app

```
/app - root of Rails app
/client - root of React app
/public - does display index page
```

root/client/package.json

```
{
    "name": "qc_react",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "react-scripts": "^0.8.4"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^15.4.1",
        "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
        "react-router": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "cacheDirectories": [
        "node_modules",
        "client/node_modules"
    ],
    "proxy": "${API_URL}:${PORT}/v1/"
}
```

root/package.json

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This repo contains a web application codebase. Read instructions on how to install.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cd client" # not sure what to put here but this gets me past build failure
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://myrepo.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://myhomepage#readme"
}
```

Procfile

```
api: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Buildpacks

```
1. https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git
2. heroku/ruby
```

config/puma.rb

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3001
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on how do you access the app via browser?

Comment: I just use the command `heroku open` which opens my default browser (chrome) to the url of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found the solution I was looking for. My code base has the following structure.

```
app/
client/
public/
...
```

I'm currently building my client solution as @yeasayer suggested above. After building and deploying my react project to the public folder in my rails api, I added the following to my routes:

```
... # api routes ...

get '/*path', to: 'react#index'
```

Then I created a react_controller and added the following contents:

```
class ReactController < ActionController::Base
  def index
      render :file => 'public/index.html', :layout => false
  end
end
```

Now any routes not caught by the api routes, will render the react app. I'm not sure why others don't use this structure instead of using react_on_rails or some other plugin to achieve the same result. This setup is a lot simpler than dealing with these other solutions but I'd like to hear any thoughts on why this solution is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

That's because Rails is serving static files (including `index.html`) from `/public`. But your React app bundle is located inside `/client/build`. After build you need to copy these files back to Rails folder. The easiest way to do this is to add some scripts to your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "deploy": "cp -a build/. public",
  "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build && npm run deploy"
},
```

`heroku-postbuild` is executed automatically by Heroku after all dependencies are installed, just like normal `postinstall` hook.

Be careful with the paths for `cp` command. Your setup with 2 different `package.json` files is too complex. I recommend to use a single `package.json` inside root and set all paths accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the create-react-app-buildpack, but I think your issue is that your react app is in a subdirectory. Buildpacks only get executed if heroku can detect a matching application in the directory and since your package.json in your root does not match create-react-app-buildpack I don't think it is being used.

What you might try is removing the root package.json and using this [sub directory buildpack](https://github.com/negativetwelve/heroku-buildpack-subdir) so you can specify the locations of each buildpack directory

Comment: I got the sub directory buildpack installed but I'm still not able to pull up the react app. The rails app appears to work as before but i don't see or know how to get to my react app. The rails app is just an api that I want to hit it for data. What I really want to see is the front end. Right now, I'm getting the same index.html file in my public folder. What was different is that I did see it build the react app. Just don't know how to get to it.